# Use generic type of embedded generic

Tags: java, generics

i have 2 different classes. One is a generic valueHolder, that can contain anything that extends number.

```
class ValueHolder<T extends number>{
    private T currentValue;

   //more functions, database logic, etc...
}
```

the other class is more complex, and has a "targetValue". Also its parameterized like this:

```
class MoreComplexClass<T extends ValueHolder<?>>
    private T valueHolder;
    private XXX requiredValue;

    //a lot more functions.
}
```

Is it "possible" to use the Type of the valueHolder for the requiredValue of the MoreComplexClass?
What i am trying to achieve is: Beeing able to compare currentValue and requiredValue with > == < Operators without casting and without loosing Typesafety. (Maybe i'm also thinking way to complex to achiee this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is YES, you can declare the *complex class* this way:

```
class MoreComplexClass<N extends Number, T extends ValueHolder<N>>
    private T valueHolder;
    private N requiredValue;

    //a lot more functions.
}
```

but since you are using the `Number` class, you won't be able to use those operators, you'll need to use one of the `XXXvalue()` methods (i.e.: `doubleValue()`, `longValue()`) from the `Number` class to able to use those operators.

Comment: Perfect, that's what im looking for. Now i have just to think about if it helps me, or if it makes work harder :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not number implements Comparable but the derived subclasses like Integer, Double,... So theres no change in usage for the moment, except it is save now, that valueHolder and ComplexClass have the same Type.

Comment: sorry, I made that assumption, corrected now. as you say, at least your code is safer now as it encourages to use the same type in the `ValueHolder` and the `ComplexClass`, to make the comparison I would transform the value to `double` as it is the higher precision one

Answer (score 0):

Due to the comments i made some changes, and it looks now like this:

```
public class ValueHolder<T extends Comparable<T>> {
private T currentValue;

public T getCurrentValue() {
    return currentValue;
}

public void setCurrentValue(T currentValue) {
    this.currentValue = currentValue;
}
}

public class MoreComplexClass<N extends Comparable<N>, T extends ValueHolder<N>> {
private T valueHolder;
private N requiredValue;

public N getRequiredValue() {
    return requiredValue;
}

public void setRequiredValue(N requiredValue) {
    this.requiredValue = requiredValue;
}

public T getValueHolder() {
    return valueHolder;
}

public void setValueHolder(T valueHolder) {
    this.valueHolder = valueHolder;
}
}
```

Now i'm able to do the comparision in an Generic way, too (this is essentiell, because i dont want to cast to every possible types. On a Sidenote, this will now work for Dates etc, too.):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ValueHolder<Long> longHolder = new ValueHolder<>();
    longHolder.setCurrentValue(2L);

    MoreComplexClass<Long, ValueHolder<Long>> mcc = new MoreComplexClass<>();
    mcc.setRequiredValue(1L);

    int compare = mcc.getRequiredValue().compareTo(mcc.getValueHolder().getCurrentValue());

    if (compare < 0) {

    } else if (compare > 0) {

    }else{

    }
}
}
```

I'll leave you with the solution tick for pointing me in the right direction ;)